# matching non-unique values to unique values

Tags: awk, sed

I have data which looks like this

```
1   3
1   2
1   9
5   4
4   6
5   6
5   8
5   9
4   2
```

I would like the output to be

```
  1    3,2,9
  5    4,6,8,9
  4    6,2
```

This is just sample data but my original one has lots more values.

Comment: Edit your question to show what you have tried so far. Even if it's just pseudo-code it'd show some effort on your part to solve your problem and so motivate others to help you. BTW to help you figure out which tool you need: grep is for printing a string matching a regexp in a file - that is not what you are trying to do. sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines - that is also not what you are trying to do. awk is for all other text manipulation - that IS what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with awk.

Comment: Great then, again - **Edit your question to show what you have tried so far.**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this worked

So this basically creates a hash table, using the first column as a key and the second column of the line as the value:

```
awk '{line="";for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) line = line $i ", "; table[$1]=table[$1] line;} END {for (key in table) print key " => " table[key];}' trial.txt
```

OUTPUT

```
 4 => 6, 2
 5 => 4, 6, 8, 9 
 1 => 3, 2, 9
```

Comment: If that is your attempt and you still need help to produce the output you say you want in your question then delete this answer and instead edit your question to include this script and explain why it's inadequate. If you're saying you've figured out a solution you're happy with and don't need help then just delete your question so no-one else wastes time looking at it.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write

```
awk -v OFS=, '
    {
        key = $1
        $1 = ""
        values[key] = values[key] $0
    }
    END {
        for (key in values) {
            sub(/^,/, "", values[key])
            print key " " values[key]
        }
    }
' file
```

If you want only the unique values for each key (requires GNU awk for multi-dimensional arrays)

```
gawk -v OFS=, '
    { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) values[$1][$i] = i }
    END {
        for (key in values) {
            printf "%s ", key
            sep = ""
            for (val in values[key]) {
                printf "%s%s", sep, val
                sep = ","
            }
            print ""
        }
    }
' file
```

or perl

```
perl  -lane '
    $key = shift @F;
    $values{$key}{$_} = 1 for @F;
} END {
    $, = " ";
    print $_, join(",", keys %{$values{$_}}) for keys %values;
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

if not concerned with the order of the keys, I think this is the idiomatic `awk` solution.

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=($1 in a?a[$1]",":"") $2} 
    END{for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' file | 
 column -t

4  6,2
5  4,6,8,9
1  3,2,9
```